# Initializing n integers in 2-dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm having a difficult time understanding how I can initialize and add 1 to `n` integers to each element in a 2-dimensional array.

For example if `n = 5`,

`arr[5][5] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} };`

I have tried

`for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(arr[i]); j++) {
        product[i][j] += 1;
    }
}`

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: @AndrewLi That's what I initially tried however `arr.length` doesn't exist in C. I tried `sizeof(arr)` but I couldn't get a correct array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a starting point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 5

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int arr[LENGTH][LENGTH] = { { 0 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%p contains %d elements\n", (void *) arr[i], (int) sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
        for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
            arr[i][j]++;
            fprintf(stderr, "%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that you can only do the `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(*foo)` trick because `foo` is on the stack. You can't do this with dynamically allocated memory via pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However your solution prints `1 1 1 1 1` instead of `1 2 3 4 5`. How do I add each element?

Comment: I'm trying not to do your work for you, and instead try to give you a working start point to solve the problem. You could think about the value of `j` and perhaps add that value to `arr[i][j]`, instead of doing `arr[i][j]++`. Work through the loop and investigate what the initial and final values are. You can then modify the calculation in the loop to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

So if I am understanding you're question right, you want to add 1 to each element in you're curent array `arr[5][5] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} }`?

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 5

void print_array(int arr[][COLS], int nrows);

int
main(void) {
    int row, col;
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};

    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            arr[row][col] += 1;
        }
    }

    print_array(arr, ROWS);

    return 0;
}

void
print_array(int arr[][COLS], int nrows) {
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Or if you really want to use `sizeof()`, you can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 5

int
main(void) {
    int row, col;
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    int row_size, col_size;

    row_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    col_size = sizeof(*arr)/sizeof(**arr);

    for (row = 0; row < row_size; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < col_size; col++) {
            arr[row][col] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (row = 0; row < row_size; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < col_size; col++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong condition in for loop
sizeof(arr) gives 5(rows)*5(col)*4(integer size) = 100;

Hence your for loop results in undefined behavior 
sizeof(arr[0]) gives 5*4=20;

You have to use

```
rows_count=size(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
col_count=sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]);
```

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,j;
    int arr[5][5]={{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}};
    printf("Sizeof(arr) : %d\n",sizeof(arr));
    printf("Sizeof(arr[0]) : %d\n",sizeof(arr[0]));
    for (int i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++) 
    {
        for (int j=0;j<(sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]));j++) 
            arr[i][j] += 1;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));i++) 
    {
        for (int j=0;j<(sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[0][0]));j++) 
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
        printf("\n");

}
```